# Why is getByRole not working in this case?

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm having a hard time understanding why my assertion isn't working.

Here's the DOM:

```html
<h4>
  <span aria-hidden="true">foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</h4>
```

And here's my assertion:

```js
screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /foo/i, hidden: true })
```

I've read the [documentation on the hidden flag](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#hidden), but i'm still having trouble understanding why this isn't working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is where you're setting the aria-hidden attribute, as it is not being set to the h1, which has the heading role.

I made a [CodeSandBox demo with failing test](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-63249?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js) when the aria-hidden is set within the h1 tag.

Comment: Could you copy the relevant parts of your sandbox into the answer? Links rot over time. Thanks.